# accessing class properties that are arrays in HEREDOC

Tags: php, heredoc

There's two different syntaxes in the example below. One works and the other does not! Actually I would expect it to be the other way round. The second syntax looks quite crappy to me.

```
<?php
class Vodoo
{
    public $foo = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3);
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        $return = <<<HEREDOC
<p>$this->foo[one]</p>      // outputs: "Array[one]"
<p>{$this->foo['two']}</p>  // outputs correct: "2"

HEREDOC;
        return $return;
    }
}
$bar = new Vodoo;
echo $bar->getFoo();
?>
```

Is it ok to use these curly braces and quote the associative index inside the HEREDOC?

**edit**: The expression inside the curly braces has to be written the way it'd appear outside the string!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is valid.

In heredocs and double quoted strings you can use the syntax `{$...}` where `...` is any valid PHP expression following a `$`.

This is similar to the `#{...}` syntax in Ruby, for example.

There is an example of this in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-71

See [**complex curly syntax**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: thanx for the quick reply. I saw that example from the manual. I'm just wondering about the quotes around the associative index ['...'] Are these ok, too? I mean, I just learned that in HEREDOC you don't make them and a simpler $foo[bar] works fine!

Comment: Yes this works, this is the correct syntax. You can place everything in `{...}`, provided that it starts with a `$`. In `$foo[bar]`, `bar` is a constant, and this works only because PHP assumes it value to be `bar`. So, use `$foo['bar']` instead.

Comment: complex curly syntax says: "Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string"! This is what I missed! Thanks for the link to the curly braces!

Answer (score 3):

Let's divide it to make it more clear, starting with the one that works:

```
<p>{$this->foo['two']}</p>  // outputs correct: "2"
```

It just works.

Now let's look at the other one, you think it does not work:

```
<p>$this->foo[one]</p>      // outputs: "Array[one]"
```

What actually happens here is this:

`$this->foo` is read as the variable name that will be converted into a string. Which is `Array` then. Comparable to:

```
echo $this->foo; # Array
```

The rest that follows is just parsed as string, that's why you get

```
<p>Array[one]</p>
```

for

```
<p>$this->foo[one]</p>      // outputs: "Array[one]"
```

Which is the same as:

```
<p>{$this->foo}[one]</p>      // outputs: "Array[one]"
```

The curly braces help PHP to do the parsing right. You can more specifically express which part you would like to be the variable expression in a string with curly braces.

Comment: Thanx to You as well :-) Unfortunately I can only mark on answer as my accepted one. But this one helped as well!